# Sort items by BBD in FIFO order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table Inventory that stores inventory items over several locations in particular sequence. Suppose I have the following records in the table:

```
Item  BBD          Location  Sequence 
P1    2016-04-13   LOC_01    1
P1    2016-04-16   LOC_01    2
P1    2016-04-14   LOC_01    3
P1    2016-04-12   LOC_02    1
P1    2016-04-14   LOC_02    2
P1    2016-04-15   LOC_02    3
```

The Sequence column defines the sequence (or position) of the item in its location. Considering each location can only be accessed in FIFO order, my goal is to sort the records by BBD in such a way that all items in each location must always be retrieved sequentially. For example, with the records above, the result should be like this:

```
Item  BBD          Location  Sequence 
P1    2016-04-12   LOC_02    1
P1    2016-04-13   LOC_01    1
P1    2016-04-14   LOC_02    2
P1    2016-04-15   LOC_02    3
P1    2016-04-16   LOC_01    2
P1    2016-04-14   LOC_01    3
```

Am I able to, and how can I do this with sql query?

Edit: I can't simply do `order by bbd, sequence` or `order by sequence, bbd` as it would break the sequential order of the items in a location in the first case, or return items rows by rows across locations in the second case. Basically I can only access each location from the front and I must always retrieve the oldest BBD inventory first across these locations. The result should ask me to dig as deeply as possible into a location if it has the oldest BBD inventory then ask me to go to the front of another location with second oldest BBD inventory and dig into it and so on.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is "BBD"?

Comment: Oracle, BBD denotes best before date and is a date column.

Comment: Why `P1, 2016-04-15, LOC_02, 3` is before `P1, 2016-04-14, LOC_01, 3`?

Comment: Cos `P1, 2016-04-16, LOC_01, 2` comes before `P1, 2016-04-14, LOC_01, 3` in location LOC_01 and each location must only be accessed in FIFO order.